# Pynput Listener with TKinter and comparing Listener Output

Tags: python, tkinter, pynput

I recently asked a question about TKinter's `<KeyPress>` and `<KeyRelease>` functions, and was eventually directed to using Pynput's Listener.

My only issue is that the listener does not seem to output or return a character that I can compare to a string. In the code below, Lines 34-64 are my issue - specifically, lines 35, 42, 49, and 56. These `if` statements *should* take the key returned from the Listener and, if they are the same, move my character in TKinter. However, no matter how I seem to format the `if` statements, it doesn't seem to work properly.

I originally thought that Listener was returning just the character, but testing with print statements seem to indicate that it is returning the character with single quotes on either side.

Any ideas on how to compare the item from Listener to a string? Thanks so much!

```
# Import Tkinter
from tkinter import *
from pynput import keyboard

# Create Window
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack()

# Create Background and Walls
background = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000, fill='gray')
ground = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 840, 1000, 1000, fill='black')
leftwall = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 30, 1000, fill='black')
rightwall = canvas.create_rectangle(970, 0, 1000, 1000, fill='black')
skybox = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 25, fill='black')

# Create Character Models
character = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50, fill='lightblue')

# Set Character start position
canvas.move(character, 500, 500)

# Get Character Position
x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
xpos = ((x1 - x0) / 2) + x0
ypos = ((y1 - y0) / 2) + y0

# Global Variables
contact = False
throwvar = ""


# Define Movements
def move_character(whatkey):
    if whatkey == "'w'":
        canvas.move(character, 0, -10)
        print("Moved up")
        root.after(20, move_character, whatkey)
        xbounds()
        ybounds()

    elif whatkey == "'a'":
        canvas.move(character, -10, 0)
        print("Moved left")
        root.after(20, move_character, whatkey)
        xbounds()
        ybounds()

    elif whatkey == "'d'":
        canvas.move(character, 10, 0)
        print("Moved right")
        root.after(20, move_character, whatkey)
        xbounds()
        ybounds()

    elif whatkey == "'s'":
        canvas.move(character, 0, 10)
        print("Moved down")
        root.after(20, move_character, whatkey)
        xbounds()
        ybounds()

    else:
        print("Listener doesn't work :(")


# Run Detection for if a key is released after being held
def on_press(key):
    whatkey = key
    move_character(whatkey)
    print('Pressed Key %s' % key)


def on_release(key):
    print('Released Key %s' % key)


# Apply constant downwards force while above y co-ords of 'ground'
def gravity():
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
    ypos = ((y1 - y0) / 2) + y0
    canvas.move(character, 0, 10)
    if ypos >= 800:
        root.after(20, anti)
    elif ypos <= 800 and contact == False:
        root.after(20, gravity)
        xbounds()
        ybounds()
    else:
        print("Gravity Error")


# Stop gravity when hitting 'ground'
def anti():
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
    ypos = ((y1 - y0) / 2) + y0
    canvas.move(character, 0, 0)
    if ypos <= 800:
        root.after(20, gravity)
    else:
        root.after(20, anti)
    xbounds()
    ybounds()


# Set bounds of screen, left/right
def xbounds():
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
    if x0 <= 25:
        print("Horizontal Contact, Left!")
        canvas.coords(character, 25, y0, 75, y1)
    elif x1 >= 975:
        print("Horizontal Contact, Right!")
        canvas.coords(character, 900, y0, 950, y1)


def ybounds():
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(character)
    if y0 <= 25:
        print("Vertical Contact, Upper!")
        canvas.coords(character, x0, 25, x1, 75)
    elif y1 >= 975:
        print("Vertical Contact, Lower!")
        canvas.coords(character, x0, 925, x1, 975)


# Implement Gravity
root.after(500, gravity)


# Bind keys
def listen_to_me():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release, move_character=move_character) as listener:
        root.mainloop()
        listener.join()


# Focus
root.focus_set()

# Start input code
listen_to_me()
```

Comment: Why dont you use just tkinter to detect the key? With tkinter you could just do `event.keysym` and get what you want.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you would need pynput. Tkinter's event system is remarkably flexible. What are you trying to accomplish that you think you need pynput for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer by taking the string of what Listener returns, finding the `index[1]` of said return, and using that to move. Also removed the `root.after(20, move_character, whatkey)` in my move function as it was recursing itself infinitely, which was not helpful.